# Date calculation program that adds 7 days to date entered by user

Tags: c, function

I'm currently creating a date calculation c program that adds 7 days to the date entered by the user. It must pass the data in and out of a custom function. But
when I run the code below the newDate is always 0/7/0. I'm sure the problem is with my custom function, but I cannot find where the problem is. I'm new to programming and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct date {
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
    };

struct date addSeven(struct date addSev) {
    addSev.day += 7;
 // Months with 31 days
    if ((addSev.month == 1 || // January
        addSev.month == 3 || // March
        addSev.month == 5 || // May
        addSev.month == 7 || // July
        addSev.month == 8 || // August
        addSev.month == 10 || // October
        addSev.month == 12) // December
        && addSev.day > 31) {
            addSev.day -= 31; // Equivalent to addSev.day = addSev.day - 31;
            addSev.month += 1;
            }
    // Months with 30 days
        else if ((addSev.month == 4 || // April
        addSev.month == 6 || // June
        addSev.month == 9 || // September
        addSev.month == 11) // November
        && addSev.day > 30) {
            addSev.day -= 30;
            addSev.month += 1;
            }
    // February
        else {
            if (addSev.year % 4 == 0 && addSev.day > 29) { // Leap year
                addSev.day -= 29;
                addSev.month += 1;
                }
            else if (addSev.day > 28) {
                addSev.day -= 28;
                addSev.month += 1;
                }
            }
    if ((addSev.day == 25)
            && addSev.day > 31) {
            addSev.day -= 31; // Equivalent to addSev.day = addSev.day - 31;
            addSev.month += 1;
            }
        else if ((addSev.day == 24)
                && addSev.day > 30) {
                    addSev.day -= 30;
                    addSev.month += 1;
                    }
        else {
            if (addSev.year % 4 == 0 && addSev.day > 29) { // Leap year
                addSev.day -= 29;
                addSev.month += 1;
                }
            else if (addSev.day > 28) {
                addSev.day -= 28;
                addSev.month += 1;
                }
         if (addSev.month > 12) {
            addSev.month = 1; addSev.year += 1;
            }
        return addSev;
        }
    }

int main () {
    struct date origDate, newDate;
    newDate = addSeven (origDate);
    printf("Please enter a date in mm/dd/yyyy format: ");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d",&origDate.month,&origDate.day,&origDate.year);

    printf("\n%d/%d/%d\n", origDate);
    printf("\n%d/%d/%d\n", newDate);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `if() ... else ...` in the `// February
        else {` part lack a `addSev.month == 2` condition.

Comment: do `newDate = addSeven (origDate);` after enter date. `printf("\n%d/%d/%d\n", origDate);` : Need arguments each member of `origDate`.

Comment: Where do you check that your user was paying attention and didn't enter `2017/09/07`1 as the date, for example?  In fact, where do you check that they didn't enter `2017-09-07` as the date?  Input validation is hard.

Answer (score 0):

Function call is before entering data. [@BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46104887/date-calculation-program-that-adds-7-days-to-date-entered-by-user#comment79172849_46104887).  Call `addSeven()` after `origDate` is populated.

```
// newDate = addSeven (origDate);
printf("Please enter a date in mm/dd/yyyy format: ");
scanf("%d/%d/%d",&origDate.month,&origDate.day,&origDate.year);
newDate = addSeven(origDate);
```

The `if() ... else ...` in the `// February else {` part lacks a `addSev.month == 2` condition.

Code is quite convoluted and so recommend a re-write.

```
int IsLeapYear(int year) {
  // Left for OP to code leap year detection - see far below link.
}

int DaysPerMonth(int year, int month) {
  // Left for OP to code the more simple task of finding the number of days in a month
  ... if (IsLeapYear(year)) ...
}

struct date addSeven(struct date addSev) {
  addSev.day += 7;

  int dpm = DaysPerMonth(addSev.year, addSev.month);  

  if (addSev.day > dpm) {
    addSev.day -= dpm;
    addSev.month++; // next month
    const int mpy = 12;
    if (addSev.month > mpy) {
      addSev.month -= mpy;
      addSev.year++; // next year
    }
  }
  return addSev;
}
```

BTW: `addSev.year % 4 == 0` is an overly simplistic detection for [leap year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Gregorian_calendar).